# Unable to load ggplot2 in R even after downloading

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm unable to load ggplot2 package even though I have installed other packages.
Can someone help. I'm attaching the error message below:

```
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘digest’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.0.2 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

Comment: Try updating R. "Warning message: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.0.2" suggests your R installation is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

First try re-installing ggplot2. 
The warning results from the package being built under an older version.
If that fails, update both R and all the packages you need. 
Finally look at Tal Galili's package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/index.html

His package makes it easy for you to update both R and all the packages you have already installed. ( I am assuming you're on a Windows OS)

Comment: No success with reinstalling ggplot2 and R 3.0.2. The same error message continues: Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘digest’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’. btw, I had to  do a system restore for my windows OS. is that a reason? however, i'm able to install all other packages

Comment: what's the output of .libPaths? perhaps you have the libraries installed elsewhere?

Comment: libraries are in the win3.0 directory with all the other packages. I'm unable to load only ggplot2. Now the error is Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘digest’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
what is the DLL 'digest'

Comment: install the package digest or try this  install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=T). ggplot2 is complaining about not finding the package digest. See this page http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html for packages it depends, imports and suggests

Comment: thank you very much. installed a lot many packages individually - finally ggplot is up and working