# How to install caret package in R, getting error on ggplot2

Tags: r, installation, dependencies, package

I am trying to work on a prediction model. and I need caret package in R to be installed. but whatever i try im still getting the following error:

```
**d package: ggplot2
Error in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib) : 
  DLL ‘digest’ not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded**
```

i have tried install all kinds of packages and still im getting the same error... please let me know what i should. im also using the latest version of R.

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lattice_0.20-29

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] class_7.3-11 grid_3.1.1   tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Under Windows I imagine?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with `ggplot`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205262/unable-to-load-ggplot2-in-r-even-after-downloading (sorry, don't have a Windows machine, so I can't really help more than that)

Comment: Please post the result of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: @nico i did refer to that blog. installed a lot of packages and still its not working.. two days ago when i installed the caret it was working and was able to do a few prediction models but then yesterday im unable to load the caret package. i reinstalled R too

Comment: I'm able to install and load this successfully on Windows 7. Perhaps try loading `digest` first.

Comment: @thomas two days ago it did work fine. but yesterday it started giving me errors

Comment: Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/hp/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/Rcpp/R/Rcpp.rdb': No such file or directory
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded this is what am getting now after loading digest first.

Comment: The error message is telling you that package ‘ggplot' is a dependency of 'caret', but is not installed. So either install dependencies automatically, or else install ggplot2 first.